# How to detect a Url is BookMark Format

Tags: regex, url, bookmarks

Help

i want open url in new window
,bookmarkformt url open in current Webbrowser

i have a simple way to detect bookmark format url

> file:///D:/Administrator/Desktop/123.htm#222

which contain  .htm#  or  .htm#

this is correct bookmark format url

> // bookmark name is    222
>
> file:///D:/Administrator/Desktop/123.htm#222
>
> // bookmark name is    ##abc
>
> file:///D:/Administrator/Desktop/123.htm###abc
>
> // bookmark name is   //.HTM##.htm#abc#.html##//
>
> file:///D:/Administrator/Desktop/123.htm#//.HTM##.htm#abc#.html##//

How to detect a Url is BookMark Format?
RegularExpressions can solve this,I can not write a corrent regex?

this is my solution, but need dectect url is bookmark format

```
string htmFilename = @"D:\Administrator\Desktop\123.htm";
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.StatusTextChanged += new EventHandler(webBrowser1_StatusTextChanged);
    webBrowser1.Navigate(htmFilename);
    navigated = true;
}


private void webBrowser1_StatusTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = webBrowser1.StatusText;
}

//webBrowser1  Navigating the first time not open in new window
bool navigated = false;
private void webBrowser1_Navigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    //first time nagivate 
    if (navigated == true)
    {
        //  url is not bookmark format 
        // open in new window
        if (e.Url.ToString().Contains(".htm#") == false)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            //webBrowser1.Navigate(e.Url, true);

            //Process.Start is bettor then webBrowser1.Navigate(e.Url, true);
            //Because when url is directory link such as "file:///C:/"
            //webbrowser will open a blank window and then open the Directory
            
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(e.Url.ToString());
        }
    }
    textBox2.Text = e.Url.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below regex would match the correct Bookmark format,

```
file:\/\/\/[^\.]*\.(?:htm|html)#+.*
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/vT3oW0)

OR

```
file:\/\/\/D:\/Administrator\/Desktop\/123\.htm#.*
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/tF3tD4)